# Conflict with Hebrew text in hyperlinked table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, hebrew

I am creating a biblical studies document which contains characters in Greek, Hebrew, Syriac, and Coptic. Normally I am able to render these characters just fine. The problem comes when I try to create a **hyperlinked** table of contents with the `{hyperref}` package (a TOC without hyperlinks does not create the problem). Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cjhebrew} % This package allows you to write in Hebrew.
% Write in Hebrew like this: \<hebrew>

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=false,
 linktoc=all,
 linkcolor=black, 
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section without Hebrew}

\section{Section with \<Hebrew>}

\end{document}
```

Trying to compile for a hyperlinked TOC throws an error--usually, "use of \end doesn't match its definition \end," but other errors are created before that, I think. I believe the problem may be with the `<>` brackets that get the Hebrew characters, but I'm not sure about this. When you comment out the `{hyperref}` stuff, it compiles fine and displays great, with the Hebrew in the TOC. But no links.

My question is, will it be possible to have a hyperlinked TOC with Hebrew text? I have the same problem with Syriac and Coptic, but I don't know if the cause is the same. I won't mind having an unlinked TOC--right now I'm just wondering if it's possible to do it a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the toc but the bookmarks. You can remove the hebrew with `\texorpdfstring`. You can enter single hebrew letters in the booksmarks with `\unichar` (needs the unicode-option):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cjhebrew} % This package allows you to write in Hebrew.
% Write in Hebrew like this: \<hebrew>

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=false,
 linktoc=all,
 linkcolor=black,
 unicode
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section without Hebrew}

\section{Section with \texorpdfstring{\<Hebrew>}{\unichar{"05D1}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example works, thanks! When I take out the `{\unichar{"05D1}}` but leave the rest, it produces the same error--will it be possible to include just a Hebrew string, or will I always have to include the `\unichar` part?

Comment: You can remove the `\unichar{...}` or replace it with something else to get some other text in the bookmarks. But you must leave the surrounding braces `{}`. That's the second argument of `\textorpdfstring`, it can be empty, but must be there.

Comment: Ok, got it. This works and has solved the problem for the other languages as well. Thanks so much for your help!